# Is it possible to get values of two different columns and different rows in a single record using Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-query-builder

So I am trying to get values of two different columns and different rows in a single record.

I have one table `ticket_thread` with following columns

- `id`
- `ticket_id` is foreign key referenced to ticket table and it helps to get all the conversation thread/replies done on a ticket by agents and clients.
- `user_id` shows the Id of the user who has replied on the ticket
- `title` shows the title of ticket usually only first record has value
- `is_internal` comment is to differentiate between team comments (value = 1)and replies done by agents or clients (value = 0)
- `updated_at` on shows the date when the reply has been made on a ticket

[image]

Now I want to have a single record for each ticket which will contain the title of conversation, id of the user who has created the latest reply on tickets and reply time provided the reply must not be an internal comment.

So for the above example My result would be like

[image]

Is it possible?

Please help me to wirte a query to fetch the desired result and if possible share the laravel query code for the same.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Use group by and group concat

```
SELECT 
  `Ticket ID`, 
  substring_index(group_concat(`User ID` order by `Replied on` desc) , ',', 1) as `User ID`,
  substring_index(group_concat(if (`Conversation Title` ='', null, `Conversation Title`) order by `Replied on` desc) , ',', 1) as `Conversation Title`,
  MAX(`Replied on`) 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `Ticket ID`
```

Comment: It works but it should not show the latest record where the value of `is_internal` is 1

Comment: Where is `is_internal` in your output table in question?